# VSCode -customize colors of element, ID & class text in scss files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I should stipulate that I know how to change `workbench.colorCustomizations` and have some editor changes already. That said, I'm trying to figure out / find the correct syntax to customize the colors in scss files. The default has everything one tan color.

s there an extension or a native way to customize the colors **within scss files** such that elements, IDs and classes can have different colors? And, can you give me an example of working syntax I can add to my settings.json.

[image]

Fake example of what I'm looking for...

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "scss.elementColor": "#CA0000,
  "scss.classColor": "#00dd00,
  "scss.pseudoClassColor": "#CCCCCC,
  "scss.idColor": "#CD078F,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want with Textmate rules and scopes.  For example, put this into your settings.json:

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": "entity.name.tag.css",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#00ff00",  // fontstyle property as well
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "entity.other.attribute-name.id.css",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#ff0000",
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "entity.other.attribute-name.class.css",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#0000ff",
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "entity.other.attribute-name.pseudo-element.css",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#000",
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

[image: scss scopes in color demo]

Works for both `css` and `scss`.  You could limit it to one or other if you wish with more scopes.

Get your scopes using the `Scope Inspector Tool` from the Command Palette and see more at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_editor-syntax-highlighting and https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_editor-semantic-highlighting.

Comment: Do you happen to if it's possible to change the *text* color of highlighted text? I know how to change the background highlight color, but not the text itself.

Comment: See open issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/36490  I don't think you can set that color except in high contrast themes.